# Cannot install html package with pip in virtualenv

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

In my root project folder I have created a virtual environment for python 3.4 using the following commands:

```
$ virtualenv -p /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin/python3.4 venv
$ source venv/bin/activate
```

Now I would like to install some packages with pip only for this project and I do:

```
$ venv/bin/pip install html
```

And I get the following error (full traceback except I have replaced path with '...'):

```
Collecting html
  Using cached html-1.16.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2218, in _find_and_load_unlocked
    AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__path__'

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 3, in <module>
      File ".../venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
        from setuptools.extension import Extension
      File ".../venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools/extension.py", line 8, in <module>
        from .dist import _get_unpatched
      File ".../venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 16, in <module>
        from setuptools.depends import Require
      File ".../venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools/depends.py", line 6, in <module>
        from setuptools import compat
      File ".../venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools/compat.py", line 44, in <module>
        from html.entities import name2codepoint
    ImportError: No module named 'html.entities'; 'html' is not a package

    ----------------------------------------
    Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/xz/15p_y6cn09bdc55vkvx6vrd80000gn/T/pip-build-lgl2qvpz/html
```

**Note** that I can install this package without problems globally for python 2.7.5 which is the default version on my mac.

The package I am trying to install is this one: 
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/html/1.16

Comment: You should use pyenv instead of virtualenv for python 3.4, try to look at this: https://robinwinslow.co.uk/2013/12/26/python-3-4-virtual-environment/

Comment: No, still the same problem. I guess it's a problem with this package since I can install others with no issue. I also get it if I do: ```/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin/pip3.4 install html```directly

Comment: I guess the problem here is that the package claims to be python3 compatible, but actually it's not.

Comment: The code itself is indeed python 3 compatible the problem is installing it. Since there is only one file I ended up just copying locally and importing it to my project...

Comment: with python 3.4.3, I get "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'", and this is with "html-1.16"

Answer (score 0):

This package is obsolete not compatible with current packaging tools, its last release was more than 8 years ago. I really doubt that packages published so long time ago are still usable with recent python(s).